# How to show on top one workbook after a filter in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that do a filter on vba and in order to put the data that is going to use in the filter i use an userform, that part is working (in part thanks to the users of this page so thanks again.. :P) but the issue now is that if there is another book already open it doesn't bring the one i'm using to the top.
Another issue is that i use the `Workbooks("Database 2017 plus").Windows(1).Visible = True/False` in order to hide the book when the userform is shown but at the same time don't hide others books that were open in that moment and it work but as long as the userform is active i can't use those other books and i' d like to if its possible.

Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub AllIssues_Click()
Unload Me
Workbooks("Database 2017 plus").Windows(1).Visible = True

With Workbooks("Database 2017 plus")

sheets("reported").Visible = True
sheets("reported").Select
sheets("datos").Unprotect
sheets("datos").Visible = True
sheets("principal").Visible = True
sheets("History slot").Unprotect
sheets("history slot").Visible = True

End With

End Sub
```

And about the other issue with show 0 works thanks

Comment: How the userform is showing, modal or not? Use "userformName.Show 0" to be able to work in another workbook or worksheet.

Comment: do you disable `application.screenupdating = false` and not re-enable it again?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I edit my question in order to add the code